# List all content of all files in the directory UNIX

Tags: command-line, unix, find

How to list all files-content in a directory?

something like `ls -la | cat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command, recursive :

> find /path/to/folder -type f -exec cat {} \;

Non-recursive version (due to popular pression) :

> find /path/to/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cat {} \;

Comment: This would recurse into subdirectories too, be careful.

Comment: Both version are now on !

Answer (score 4):

The following command:

```
find ./ -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

would find only files (`-type f`) from the current folder (`./`).

Studer's answer is good, and excluding directories is a good idea because it is an undefined behavior between unices, read grawity's comment.
Here are two known behaviors :

- `cat` on Linux will throw an error message when trying to cat a directory `cat: ./folder: Is a directory`).
- `cat` on FreeBSD will dump the raw directory, as stored on-disk.

If you need more information about the command or something more about it, please reply and I will annotate more/help you.

Edit:
As *John T* pointed out, this command **will** go into every sub-directories. If you need only to cat files from the current directory, you would need `-maxdepth 1`, thus giving:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

The `-maxdepth n` option can also be used to limit it to an *`n`* amount of sub-directories, 1 being the current directory, 2 being the current directory and its direct descendants, and so on.

Comment: edit just for you ;)

Comment: In _Linux_, `cat` would throw an error message. In FreeBSD, for example, it would type the raw directory as it is stored on disk. (Not very useful.)